# How to add a HTML RSVP Form in a reply email from a hyperlinked image in Outlook

Tags: outlook

I created a PNG invitation with a RSVP button which I copied to the body of an Microsoft Outlook email. I clicked the Hyperlinked option which took me to a screen where I chose the Email Address option. By adding the email address in the required section I tested it by sending it to myself but when I opened the email and clicked on the image, the reply mail in a separate screen opened with only the mail to and subject section filled in. What do I do to get the email to open with the html form embedded in the email which the recipient can fill in and RSVP? Please help, I am on deadline.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Anyone is there another option that can possess the identical outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can't - mailto url only lets you pass recipients, subject, and body. No HTML body or attachments are possible.